# Unix architecture - Is daemon process run in kernel level or user level?

Tags: unix, daemon

What level do daemon processes like init, httpd, ftpd, dhcpd, etc run? Is it in kernel level or user level like shell, library functions and applications?

I read several Unix books and internet articles but none mention where do they run.

Answer (score 1):

They run in userspace but with root privileges for some of them. There is no requirement for a daemon (in general) to run in kernel space. Kernel space is restricted for tasks that handle the lowest level of interaction with the hardware (drivers) and back the vital functions of the OS (memory management, file system, etc.).

Comment: +1: I'm not sure whether 'kernel space' and 'processes' really go together; there aren't really processes running down at that level.  But the basic point is correct — daemons run in user space.